# mp4 conversion using users computers instead of server processing power?

Tags: javascript, html, video, cpu, mp4

I have a video service where users upload their videos and I need to convert it to mp4 in several resolutions, there is a way using html5 or java (ideally not java) where when the user upload his video run an mp4 conversion using his computer power instead of my server cpu?

Comment: I think you're going to run into some licensing restrictions since you would have to effectively license the codec for each user.  I'm not a lawyer though... I don't know for sure.  Codec licensing is complicated.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025600/h-264-video-encoder-in-javascript

Comment: probably if I use an opensource library/codec could work

Comment: Open source does not get you around licenses. X264 is open source, but still must be licensed from mpegla.